# Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> string $templatePath ]]

Tags: php, laravel-8

**Warning :** This question is Laravel 8 specific

I made a login with middleware, but I got an error when I wanted to access the dashboard

i am getting the following error :
"Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [  string $templatePath ]] in class SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\Report\Html\Renderer"

[an error appears like this, but I don't understand it at all]

[This is the syntax that detected an error in App \ Http \ Middleware \ CekUserLogin : 26 in part "return $next(request());"

```
use Closure;
```

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class CekUserLogin

{

```
/**

 * Handle an incoming request.

 *

 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request

 * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next

 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse

 */

public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, $rules)

{


    if(!Auth::check()){

        return redirect('login');

    }


    $user = Auth::user();

    if($user->level == $rules){

        return $next(request());

    }

        return redirect('login')->with('error',"Kamu tidak ada akses");


}
```

}

when I debug it, it appears like this

select * from `users` where `id` = ? limit 1

I want to be able to successfully access the login to the dashboard without error, I beg for your help
Thank You

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.